# SVG offset issue in firefox

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-svg

In Firefox 12.0 or greater, `.offset()` and `.position()` are returning unexpected values when called on SVG (root) elements.

The resulting values are the x-coord of the most left child for the 'left' component and the y-coord of the most top child for the 'top' component.

```
$(this.SvgObject).offset().left / $(this.SvgObject).offset().top
```

returns un expected value in firefox.

but when i getting the parent offset it gives the correct value (i.e.):

```
$(this.SvgObject).parent().offset().left
```

but it is not correct way to do it.

Please refer to [this bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9797). They replied with:

> "Unfortunately we're not planning on fixing bugs relating to SVG any time soon:"

How can I solve this in SVG?

Comment: If your root svg element has a viewBox then it's probably your expectations that are incorrect and not a bug in Firefox or jquery. You haven't shown us the SVG or told us what numbers you expect from it though.

Comment: Robert> the most relaxed expectation with jquery is having the same results (buggy or correct) in all browsers, it's clearly not the the case here. Chrome and FF return different things.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, i just created a fake boundary before starting to draw the Raphael diagram, that solved the issue.

```
// adding following rect just to set the boundary of svg element (firefox)
paper.rect(0,0,paperWidth,paperHeight,0).attr({stroke: "#fff"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var svg = $(this.SvgObject),
    po = svg.offsetParent().offset(),

    left = po.left + parseInt(svg.css("left"), 10),
    top = po.top + parseInt(svg.css("top"), 10);
```